# touch events not registering on libgdx sprites

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using libgdx to make a card game but I have hit a deadlock.

1. Touches or clicks on sprites are not being detected.
2. There is extra space that appears on my board which is not there in the

   tiled map file.
   I made a simple project to illustrate my problem.
   A compilable project is here that shows the code in its enterity https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51343591/card.zip

   ```
   public class Card extends ApplicationAdapter {
       SpriteBatch batch;
       TmxMapLoader tmxMapLoader;
       TiledMap tiledMap;
       OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;
       OrthographicCamera camera;
       Viewport gamePort;
       Sprite cardSprite;
       Sprite dotSprite;
       Vector3 screenPointTouched;

   @Override
   public void create () {
       batch = new SpriteBatch();
       tmxMapLoader=new TmxMapLoader();
       tiledMap= tmxMapLoader.load("level1.tmx");
       mapRenderer=new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
       float worldwidth=19*16;//19tiles*16pixelspertile. This is what its like on the level1.tmx file
       float worldheight=12*16;//12tiles*16pixelspertile. This is what its like on the level1.tmx file
       gamePort= new StretchViewport(worldwidth,worldheight,camera);//new StretchViewport(,
       camera= new OrthographicCamera(10,10*(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
       camera.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth()/2,gamePort.getWorldHeight()/2,0);//center the camera
       cardSprite=new Sprite(new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
       dotSprite=new Sprite(new Texture("dot.png"));
       screenPointTouched=new Vector3();
       positionCardSpriteFromFirstRectangle();
   }

   @Override
   public void render () {
       update();
       Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
       mapRenderer.render();
       batch.begin();
       cardSprite.draw(batch);
       dotSprite.draw(batch);
       batch.end();
   }

   private void positionCardSpriteFromFirstRectangle() {
       MapObject mo=tiledMap.getLayers().get("cardlayer").getObjects().get(0);//get the firstone onlys
       Rectangle rect=((RectangleMapObject)mo).getRectangle();
       cardSprite.setBounds(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);
   }

   public void update() {
       camera.update();
       mapRenderer.setView(camera);
       if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){//handle touch event
           screenPointTouched.set(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),0);
           screenPointTouched=camera.unproject(screenPointTouched);
           if(cardSprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(screenPointTouched.x,screenPointTouched.y)){
               System.out.println("being touched");
               dotSprite.setPosition(screenPointTouched.x,screenPointTouched.y);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Have you considered using a `Stage` and then registering the input handler?

Comment: I guess I should try Stage. But am used to working with sprites and TMX maps. @munyul is it easy to incorporate animations into stage?

Comment: honestly, I don't know. I've used the `Stage` class for the 2 libGDX projects that I've worked on and I've found it easy to use - however, I've never used the `Animiation` classes, but I would assume it shouldn't be a problem.